# jQuery trouble with selectors

Tags: jquery-mobile

I thought I knew jq selectors but this is killing me. Given this html snippet (which was dynamically added to a jquery mobile form):

```
    <li class="ld ui-li-divider ui-bar-inherit" data-role="list-divider" 
        role="heading">Monday&nbsp;
    <label class="dateInput" style="display: none;">Choose a 
        Date to attend:<input type="text" id="dateInput1" name="dateInput1" 
        class="dateInput" 
        data-role="date" data-inline="false" style="display: none;">
    </label>
    </li>
    <li class="hn ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-li-has-thumb">
    <input type="checkbox" class="catChk" id="chkH10" name="chkH" data-week-
        day="Monday" value="">Check1</li>
    <li class="hn ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-li-has-thumb">
    <input type="checkbox" class="catChk" id="chkH11" name="chkH" data-week-
        day="Monday" value="">Check2</li>
```

The elements with `class="dateInput"` are hidden. When either Check1 or Check2 is checked I want to show the dateInput.
I've tried lots of things including:

```
    $("#dayClassList").on("click", "input.catChk", function () {
        $(this).closest(".ld").find(".dateInput").show();
    }
```

Just using `$(".dateInput").show();` works, but I have other dateInputs on the page that should stay hidden. I just want the dateInput in the closest `".ld"` to be shown. The ids are dynamically created so I can't use them. I have to work with the class selectors.

Comment: So does it mean there are more than one date input fields are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also added fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dipakchavda2912/ce9mu1q2/ 
Let me know is it resolve your issue or not?

```
<li class="ld ui-li-divider ui-bar-inherit" data-role="list-divider" 
        role="heading">Monday&nbsp;
    <label class="dateInput" style="display: none;">Choose a Date to attend:
        <input type="text" id="dateInput1" name="dateInput1" 
        class="dateInput" 
        data-role="date" data-inline="false">
    </label>
    </li>
    <li class="hn ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-li-has-thumb">
    <input type="checkbox" class="catChk" id="chkH10" name="chkH" data-week-
        day="Monday" value="">Check1</li>
    <li class="hn ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-li-has-thumb">
    <input type="checkbox" class="catChk" id="chkH11" name="chkH" data-week-
        day="Monday" value="">Check2</li>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".catChk").on("change", function (e) {
        if(true === $(this).is(":checked")){
        $.each($(".dateInput, input[id^='dateInput']"), function () {
          $(this).show();
        });
      }else{
        $.each($(".dateInput, input[id^='dateInput']"), function () {
          $(this).hide();
        });
      }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Dipak - yes there is a `<li class="ld">` with a dateInput inside it for each day of the week. Each `".ld"` is followed by numerous `<li class="hn">` lines and each `".hn"` has a checkbox.   
Your solution shows all dateInputs. I need to target the dateInput in the closest `".ld"` to the `".hn"` that is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dayClassList").on("click", "input.catChk", function () {
        $(".dateInput:first").show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dipak your answer put me on the right track. I have accepted your answer. I ended up kludging it by changing the id of the li.ln to include the dayName. This made it easy to target. When the checkbox is checked I grab the data-week-day value and find the matching li.ln with the same value.